# How to do numeric differentiation using Boost Units?

Tags: c++, differentiation, boost-units

I would like to perform a numeric differentiation in C++. For type safety, I'd like to use `boost::units` to avoid mixing units but also `boost::units::absolute` to avoid mixing relative and absolute units.

A minimal example is to calculate the velocity as a function of the change in position divided by the change in time: `v = dx/dt`, which can be approximated as `(x1 - x0)/(t1 - t0)`.

In this example `v` has an absolute unit (velocity), `dx` and `dt` relative ones (distance / duration).

While `boost::units` derives the correct unit if we simply take relative units everywhere,

```
static_assert(std::is_same<boost::units::divide_typeof_helper<
                               boost::units::si::length, 
                               boost::units::si::time>::type, 
                           boost::units::si::velocity>::value);
```

the `static_assert` fails if we want the result of our division being an absolute velocity:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<boost::units::divide_typeof_helper<
                               boost::units::si::length, 
                               boost::units::si::time>::type, 
                           boost::units::absolute<boost::units::si::velocity>>::value);
```

Am I doing a wrong assumption that the result of dividing two relative units should always yield an absolute one? Or is this an error in the implementation of `boost::units`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs on `boost::units::absolute`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost/units/absolute.html),

> **Description**
>
> A wrapper to represent absolute units (points rather than vectors).

Spacetime events are points (if not viewed as *radius vectors*), their differences are vectors. Velocity is also a vector. Thus, your assumption does indeed appear wrong.

Comment: Can't a velocity again be absolute (= position in velocity space) or relative (= vector in velocity space)? In my understanding an absolute velocity represents the velocity of a particle, a relative velocity the difference between two absolute velocities, e.g. used to compute the (absolute) acceleration.

Comment: @user2968115 it can of course, just as position can be viewed as a radius vector and thus be relative. Such subtle reinterpretations aren't something that I'd expect a generic dimensional analysis library to support. Remember how a ratio of two lengths (arc length and radius) can suddenly get a dimension of angle. This is also a case where you'd manually alter a dimension.